# Ambiguous reference to member 'downloadTask(with:completionHandler:)'

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I'm trying to play audio from URL.

```
var downloadTask:URLSessionDownloadTask!
downloadTask = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (url, response, error) in
    playAudio(url: url)
})
downloadTask.resume()
```

but this gives me error pf ambiguous reference.

[image]

Comment: I think you are using code of "Swift5" from somewhere and your project is in "Swift4", just rewrite the method and you are good to go!

Comment: no I'm not using copy paste code. I have written it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler expects native `URL`, don't use `NS...` classes in Swift anyway if there is a native equivalent.

And `downloadTask` is a non-optional constant. There is no reason to add a declaration line.

And most likely you will get another error about *requires explicit 'self.'*

```
func downloadTaskFromURL(url: URL) {
    let downloadTask = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (url, response, error) in
        self.playAudio(url: url)
    })
    downloadTask.resume()
}
```

Side note: According to the naming guidelines the method should be named `func downloadTask(from url: URL)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `URL` instead of `NSURL`

```
func downloadFile(from url: URL) {
    var downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask
    downloadTask = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (url, reponse, error) in
        // play audio
    })
    downloadTask.resume()
}
```